# One or several required parameters are missing or incorrect. An incorrect resource ID also raises this kind of error.'

Tags: wordpress

I integrated Mangopay plugin into my wordpress site for crowdfunding 
After configuring it and when i try to purchase using mangopay interface i got these errors.

```
exception 'MangoPay\ResponseException' with message 'Bad request. One or several required parameters are missing or incorrect. An incorrect resource ID also raises this kind of error.' in /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/restTool.inc:272
Stack trace:
#0 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/restTool.inc(126): MangoPay\RestTool->CheckResponseCode(Object(stdClass))
#1 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/restTool.inc(93): MangoPay\RestTool->RunRequest()
#2 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/apiBase.inc(157): MangoPay\RestTool->Request('/users/natural', 'POST', Array)
#3 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/apiUsers.inc(24): MangoPay\ApiBase->CreateObject('users_createnat...', Object(MangoPay\UserNatural))
#4 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/gateway/class-wm-fonctions-gateway.php(65): MangoPay\ApiUsers->Create(Object(MangoPay\UserNatural))
#5 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/gateway/class-wm-fonctions-gateway.php(43): WM_Fonction_Gateway::wm_create_mangopay_user(Object(WP_User))
#6 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/gateway/class-wm-woocommerce-gateway.php(104): WM_Fonction_Gateway::wm_get_mangopay_user(Object(WP_User))
#7 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php(646): WM_Woocommerce_Gateway->process_payment(1804)
#8 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php(369): WC_Checkout->process_checkout()
#9 [internal function]: WC_AJAX::checkout('')
#10 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-includes/plugin.php(496): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#11 /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(85): do_action('wp_ajax_woocomm...')
#12 {main}MangoPay\ResponseException Object
(
    [_responseCodes:MangoPay\ResponseException:private] => Array
        (
            [200] => OK
            [206] => PartialContent
            [400] => Bad request
            [401] => Unauthorized
            [403] => Prohibition to use the method
            [404] => Not found
            [405] => Method not allowed
            [413] => Request entity too large
            [422] => Unprocessable entity
            [500] => Internal server error
            [501] => Not implemented
        )

    [_errorInfo:MangoPay\ResponseException:private] => MangoPay\Error Object
        (
            [Message] => One or several required parameters are missing or incorrect. An incorrect resource ID also raises this kind of error.
            [Errors] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AuthorId] => The AuthorId field is required.
                )

        )

    [RequestUrl] => https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com/v2/rota90/payins/card/web/
    [message:protected] => Bad request. One or several required parameters are missing or incorrect. An incorrect resource ID also raises this kind of error.
    [string:Exception:private] => 
    [code:protected] => 400
    [file:protected] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/restTool.inc
    [line:protected] => 272
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/restTool.inc
                    [line] => 126
                    [function] => CheckResponseCode
                    [class] => MangoPay\RestTool
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Message] => One or several required parameters are missing or incorrect. An incorrect resource ID also raises this kind of error.
                                    [Type] => param_error
                                    [Id] => a3a12c22-1bc3-41ff-b92b-d923cd763e7f
                                    [Date] => 1427279161
                                    [errors] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [AuthorId] => The AuthorId field is required.
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/restTool.inc
                    [line] => 93
                    [function] => RunRequest
                    [class] => MangoPay\RestTool
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/apiBase.inc
                    [line] => 157
                    [function] => Request
                    [class] => MangoPay\RestTool
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /payins/card/web/
                            [1] => POST
                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [CreditedWalletId] => 6183033
                                    [CardType] => CB_VISA_MASTERCARD
                                    [ReturnURL] => http://itsaboutmyafrica.com/checkout/order-received/1804?key=wc_order_551277ae9f920
                                    [Culture] => TN
                                    [SecureMode] => DEFAULT
                                    [DebitedFunds] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => EUR
                                            [Amount] => 46000
                                        )

                                    [Fees] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => EUR
                                            [Amount] => 0
                                        )

                                    [Tag] => 1804
                                )

                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/mangoPaySDK/tools/apiPayIns.inc
                    [line] => 17
                    [function] => CreateObject
                    [class] => MangoPay\ApiBase
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => payins_card-web_create
                            [1] => MangoPay\PayIn Object
                                (
                                    [CreditedWalletId] => 6183033
                                    [PaymentType] => CARD
                                    [PaymentDetails] => MangoPay\PayInPaymentDetailsCard Object
                                        (
                                            [CardType] => CB_VISA_MASTERCARD
                                            [CardId] => 
                                        )

                                    [ExecutionType] => WEB
                                    [ExecutionDetails] => MangoPay\PayInExecutionDetailsWeb Object
                                        (
                                            [RedirectURL] => 
                                            [ReturnURL] => http://itsaboutmyafrica.com/checkout/order-received/1804?key=wc_order_551277ae9f920
                                            [TemplateURL] => 
                                            [Culture] => TN
                                            [SecureMode] => DEFAULT
                                        )

                                    [AuthorId] => 
                                    [CreditedUserId] => 
                                    [DebitedFunds] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => EUR
                                            [Amount] => 46000
                                        )

                                    [CreditedFunds] => 
                                    [Fees] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => EUR
                                            [Amount] => 0
                                        )

                                    [Status] => 
                                    [ResultCode] => 
                                    [ResultMessage] => 
                                    [ExecutionDate] => 
                                    [Type] => 
                                    [Nature] => 
                                    [Id] => 
                                    [Tag] => 1804
                                    [CreationDate] => 
                                )

                            [2] => \MangoPay\PayIn
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/gateway/class-wm-fonctions-gateway.php
                    [line] => 129
                    [function] => Create
                    [class] => MangoPay\ApiPayIns
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => MangoPay\PayIn Object
                                (
                                    [CreditedWalletId] => 6183033
                                    [PaymentType] => CARD
                                    [PaymentDetails] => MangoPay\PayInPaymentDetailsCard Object
                                        (
                                            [CardType] => CB_VISA_MASTERCARD
                                            [CardId] => 
                                        )

                                    [ExecutionType] => WEB
                                    [ExecutionDetails] => MangoPay\PayInExecutionDetailsWeb Object
                                        (
                                            [RedirectURL] => 
                                            [ReturnURL] => http://itsaboutmyafrica.com/checkout/order-received/1804?key=wc_order_551277ae9f920
                                            [TemplateURL] => 
                                            [Culture] => TN
                                            [SecureMode] => DEFAULT
                                        )

                                    [AuthorId] => 
                                    [CreditedUserId] => 
                                    [DebitedFunds] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => EUR
                                            [Amount] => 46000
                                        )

                                    [CreditedFunds] => 
                                    [Fees] => Array
                                        (
                                            [Currency] => EUR
                                            [Amount] => 0
                                        )

                                    [Status] => 
                                    [ResultCode] => 
                                    [ResultMessage] => 
                                    [ExecutionDate] => 
                                    [Type] => 
                                    [Nature] => 
                                    [Id] => 
                                    [Tag] => 1804
                                    [CreationDate] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/wordpressmangopay/includes/gateway/class-wm-woocommerce-gateway.php
                    [line] => 152
                    [function] => wm_create_payin
                    [class] => WM_Fonction_Gateway
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => http://itsaboutmyafrica.com/checkout/order-received/1804?key=wc_order_551277ae9f920
                            [2] => 1804
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php
                    [line] => 646
                    [function] => process_payment
                    [class] => WM_Woocommerce_Gateway
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1804
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php
                    [line] => 369
                    [function] => process_checkout
                    [class] => WC_Checkout
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [function] => checkout
                    [class] => WC_AJAX
                    [type] => ::
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-includes/plugin.php
                    [line] => 496
                    [function] => call_user_func_array
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => WC_AJAX
                                    [1] => checkout
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 
                                )

                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /homepages/17/d555245609/htdocs/Itsaboutmyafrica/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
                    [line] => 85
                    [function] => do_action
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => wp_ajax_woocommerce_checkout
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] => 
    [_code] => 400
)
```

I used mangopay wordpress plugin 1.0.5 with woocommerce 2.3 and ignitiondeck-crowdfunding
Could you please help me get rid from these errors?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and it turns out that Address is missing. I added

```
$user->Address = null;
```

to solve this.